# How do I return a reverse string using recursion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I need to write a method for the class "smartReverse" to return a reversed string of the the class's one private string variable: "str". There are some rules to this however:

1. I must use recursion to create a reversed string.
2. There cannot be any parameters in the method.
3. The variable "str" cannot be altered, the method must return a seperate string created inside the method ("rev_str" is my code)

I've been working on this particular method for a couple hours every day since last Wednesday, and I've gotten nowhere. Help is appreciated!

NOTE: this code comes from a test file where the "Recursive" method is just a standalone function in my "main.cpp". There is one string parameter just to simulate it being a method.

```
string Recursive(string str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
        return str;
    }
    else {
        string rev_str;
        rev_str = rev_str + str.substr(str.length() - 1 - 
                                        rev_str.length(), 1);
        if (rev_str.length() == str.length()) {
            return rev_str;
        }
        else {
            recursive(str);
        }
    }

}
```

The only results I've gotten out of my hours is overflow in "rev_str".

Comment: The key to recursive functions is to make the problem simpler with every call. How are you doing that in this case?

Comment: "There cannot be any parameters in the method." - what? How do you pass the string to be reversed?

Comment: If class can have other fields than the actual string, you can add some variables to class then you can save the reversed string in that fields.

Comment: If you are trying to make it as class method, why you added this code with Recursion function (not a class member), that's confusing.

Comment: Whoever "invented" this assignment should stop teaching. Why? 1. Reversing a string is a otherwise problem independent algorithm, which need not be polluted with the context it is used in. (simple function, no classes). 2. The extra constraints like "no additional arguments" is counter productive/obfuscation in the effort to teach recursive programming. (left vs right recursive) 3. Any sort of "global variables" should be discouraged not encouraged / here unnecessary member variables are encouraged...

Answer (score 0):

Recursion without input parameter sounds pretty senseless but you can use non-static member variables instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class smartReverse {
    std::string str;
    std::size_t counter = 0;

    std::string recursion() {
        if (counter > str.size())
            return "";
        char c = str[counter];
        if (counter == str.size() - 1)
            return std::string(1, c);
        ++counter;
        return recursion() + c;
    }
public:
    smartReverse(std::string s) : str(s) {}
    std::string reverse() {
        counter = 0;
        return recursion();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << smartReverse("Teststring").reverse() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I need to write a method for the class "smartReverse" to return a reversed string of the the class's one private string variable: "str". ". I think he is trying to make it with class method, so he can't use global variables, but class variables instead

Answer (score -2):

I don't really see the point of this exercice, but who knows…
Have a great time learning C++, hopefully we will quickly see `std::reverse`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string Recursive(string str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
        return str;
    }
    else {
        string rev_str = str.substr(str.length() - 1, 1);
        str.pop_back();
        if (str.empty()) {
            return rev_str;
        }
        else {
            string back = Recursive(str);
            rev_str+= back;
            return rev_str;
        }
    }

}
int main()
{
    std::cout<< Recursive(std::string("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you need to include <iostream> and there's also no point in writing a prototype for Recursive() in this example.

Comment: Of course @Btables, wouldn't dare not include your remarks to make this a top-notch answer !

Comment: ``using namespace std;`` is bad. Don't encourage people to do that. Also, unless there is some quirkiness at work, you don't need the second level if. Just write: ``return str.substr(str.length()-1),1) + Recursive( str.substr(0,str.length()-1));``

Comment: @PilouPili This is a beginners question most likely read by beginners. So it is better to stop annoying habits before they are considered "normal". If you do the using, you basically teach the message: "pollute your namespaces or better even do not use namespaces at all because if anyone just circumvents them anyway, they are good for nothing."

Comment: @BitTickler. Look at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/hello-world-in-c-using-visual-studio-2019/ and see what they do at step 8. I reminder my first lesson in C++ which was a loooong time ago. Guess what : using namespace std; and I turned allright I guess, thanks to the third or fourth lesson (what is a namespace).  In my mind this a typically the kind of steril debate that makes people trying to learn C++ think "Oh what the heck this seems way too complicated for me…", and that is the real shame.

Comment: @PilouPili You will be happy with people doing that until... you have to actually cold-read their code under time pressure. And the first 20 lines of the code being using namespace statements from the 20 libraries they use. And later on in reading the code, you keep wondering which functions they use came from where. But granted, it's a bit like a debate whether crossing a red light at 3am in the morning with empty streets is okay or not. Later, someone dies because when it was okay at 3am it turns into a habit.

Comment: @BitTickler OMG ! You are comparing something "punishable by law" and that implies the life of others with a coding-style !!! Could you please be a bit more restrained in your comments please. I think I have lost much more time trying to understand FORTRAN legacy code with `implicit none` and mixed with C function than being mistaken by the absence of a namespace in C++, which anyway with a proper IDE and intellisense can be quickly deduced. And thanks to ODR rule can only result in a compilation error if misused (rather not life threatening) unlike a bad cast from FORTRAN to C...